# Facebook API returns bad user id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to download messages (conversation) from FB Page. It works but there is a problem with sender's (user's) IDs. I use FB Page token and call for example this request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/105070176212618/conversations?fields=senders
```

When I try to get sender's ID, it's wrong - it doesn't exist. API returns something like this: 2065372153561988.

Can you help me, please? Do I need any extra permissions? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that´s not just an app scoped id?

Comment: Yes, API returns data, that's OK. But user's ID is wrong. There is a screenshot from Graph API Explorer: https://pasteboard.co/IhAgSJY.png.

Comment: Page-scoped instead of app-scoped then? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching